# How to use Morphia with Java / GWT

Tags: mongodb, morphia

I am trying to use MongoDB with Morphia as my back-end DB, I have implemented a utility class to simplify access to the database. I implemented basic add user function with However I am getting `lots of exceptions:

`java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException` exception when I put

> Query query = datastore.createQuery(User.class).filter("name = ",
>   username);

for checking user before comitting.

When removed: I get these two exceptions:

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: java.lang.NumberFormatException:
```

How to fix this issue?

Here are the code I have for the project:

MorphiaUtil.java:

```
public class MorphiaUtil {

    protected final Log log = LogFactory.getLog(getClass());
    private static Mongo mongo;
    private static Datastore datastore;

    static {
        try {
            // Create the database connection
            mongo =  new Mongo("localhost");
            datastore = new Morphia().createDatastore(mongo, "mygwtapp");
        } catch (UnknownHostException e) {
            System.err.println("Caught Unknown host exception:"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (MongoException e) {
            System.err.println("Initial Datastore creation failed:"+e);
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public static Datastore getDatastore() {
        return datastore;
    }
}
```

UserServiceImpl.java

```
public class UserServiceImpl extends RemoteServiceServlet 
    implements UserService {
    @Override
    public void addUser(String username, String password)
            throws IllegalArgumentException {
        try {
            Datastore datastore = MorphiaUtil.getDatastore();
            Query query = datastore.createQuery(User.class).filter("name = ", username); 
            User user = (User) query.asList().get(0);
            if (user == null) {
                user = new User(username, password);
                datastore.save(user);
            }

        } catch (Exception e) { 
            System.err.print("Caught exception:"+e);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Give us the stack traces of both exceptions.

Comment: What line is causing the exception?

Answer (score 2):

I created a server version of all my beans, and before calling saving methods, i convert from Simple Beans (used in client side) to MorphiaBeans (used only for morphia operations).

That's not the best method to fix this issue, but works fine for me!

Comment: Hi, can you share more about your solution?

Comment: I made a copy of my simple bean, in server side. This copy has all anotations from morphia, has a objectId to (this is the class not serializable that not work in gwt client). I override the save method in my DAO, and in save method i pass a SimpleBean, then i convert it to MorphiaBean (the morphia bean receives in construtor a Simple Bean), and i made the operation. If the operation needs a return (find), i convert again to SimpleBean (the morphia returns only morphiaBean, in this case). Again, this probably is not the right way to do, but works. :)

Comment: The @raduq-santos solution works fine. Remember, if you want to use some class in gwt client, it must have to be serializable, because gwt "convert" it to JS. So, morphia annotations aren't serializable for gwt, so, you need something like DTO/VO pattern. Complex beans in server side, simple beans in shared.